# C++ How should I return my byte array?

Tags: c++, arrays, memory, heap-memory

I've got a class named X (e.g.) and a public function toBytes() which returns some custom binary representation of the object.

My problem is: how should I return this byte array?

Currently, I have this:

```
uint8_t* X::toBytes()
{
    uint8_t* binData = new uint8_t[...];

    // initialize the byte array

    return binData;
}
```

The problem (or as problem considered by me as an inexperienced c++ programmer) here is that it's allocating the memory on the heap and should be freed at some point which I don't think is practical. Either the class X should free this memory in its destructor in some cumbersome way or the caller should free it. How is the caller supposed to know it is responsible for freeing the memory? It doesn't even know if it's heap memory, right?

Kinda stuck here :/

**EDIT:**

I just thought of a possible solution: let the caller supply the memory as in a pointer to a byte array and initialize that array. This would solve the problem, right?

Comment: wrap it in class, like vector, which deallocates the bytes when destructor is called, so you return `std::vector<uint8_t>` instead

Comment: _`I just thought of a possible solution: let the caller supply the memory as in a pointer to a byte array and initialize that array.`_ Yes! Overseen (but not that practical) solution!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd provide one generic solution and one convenience wrapper:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

template <typename OutIter>
void writeBytes(OutIter iter)
{
    for (...) { *iter = data(); ++iter; }
}

std::vector<uint8_t> toBytes()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> result;
    writeBytes(std::back_inserter(result));
    return result;
}
```

The generic version allows the user to interface with any kind of container they choose, and the convenience "vector" version allows the user to write something like `for (auto b : toBytes())`.

Comment: This is my general pattern too. Best of both worlds. I usually give them the same name though and let the compiler select the best overload. But I would suggest a static_assert is more helpful than using SFINAE, at least then you can give a message and keep the interface clean.

Comment: @111111: Yeah, `enable_if` is too strict, since you may well want to have some other, compatible but not identical value type.

Comment: Can I just go on record and say that while I love to see a good solution, can you also add a concrete invocation of that solution? This is not aimed at you personally and I suppose I should be complaining on meta instead, but when you don't know a subject and need help it sometimes helps to see the complete solution in context.

Comment: @PeterM: You can take `toBytes` as an example for how to use `writeBytes`, and I gave an example how to use `toBytes`...

Comment: Thanks for answering! Damn, this looks complex. What do you think of my solution I thought about after posting (see edit)? Too C-ish? And why would you pick your solution over mine?

Comment: @Yaeger: My solution is essentially the grown-up version of what you suggested in your edit :-)

Comment: @Kerrek .. but IMHO putting that solution in text removes it from the code context, so adds a bit of cognitive dissonance

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the size of the array is not known at compile time, use an [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) and return it:

```
std::vector<uint8_t> toBytes()
{
  std::vector<uint8_t> binData = ....;
  return binData;
}
```

If the size is known at compile time, then you may prefer to use an [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array):

```
std::array<uint8_t, 42> toBytes()
{
  std::array<uint8_t, 42> binData = ....;
  return binData;
}
```

Comment: I would argue the vector is preferable even if you do know the size. As the vector will "move" efficient when returned, whereas the array must copy.

Comment: @111111 the copy will most likely get elided, so the array version doesn't have to copy.

Comment: Between translation units? I think your "most likely" would become a "probably not" for and significantly complex problem.

Comment: @111111 Yes, across translation units. "Most likely" stays "most likely". Anyway, I said "may prefer to use" because there are many things to consider. But given the information given in the question, I think the above is good advice.

Comment: Thanks for answering Juanchopanza! I don't think I really want to rely on compiler optimization. The reason to use an std::array over an std::vector would be to eliminate any reallocations, I assume? If so, wouldn't the best solution be to simply create an std::vector with an initial size of e.g. 42 preventing reallocations?

Comment: @Yaeger Yes, if you initialized the vector to the correct size, it would prevent reallocations.

Comment: @Yaeger Well, there is one less level of indirection when you use an `std::array` over an `std::vector`. It is the same situation as when you use a dynamically allocated array vs. an automatic storage one. Also, even without re-allocations, the vector requires at least one dynamic allocation, and many vector instantiations could lead to memory fragmentation. On the other hand, the "stack" size is limited. So the choice between the two depends on the access patterns, sizes etc. and should follow some careful profiling, rather than theorising :)

Comment: Hmm ok, so you're implying, because the stack is limited you should... ehh... sort of balance the use of stack & heap? If so, I don't think that matters because stack and heap share the same memory region but the stack starts at the top of this region and grows downwards while the heap starts at the bottom and grows upwards. This would mean: if you never use the heap, the available space for the stack would be the complete region thus utilizing every bit of memory available. Forgive me if this is completely false or irrelevant. I'm a beginner! p.s. source: http://tinyurl.com/nqzjyun

Comment: @Yaeger I am not saying you should balance stack and heap. Usually you shouldn't have to think about that. But typically the "stack" is smaller than the "heap". So if your array is very large, you may run into trouble and then you *have* to use dynamic allocation. But only let that be a consideration if you actually run into that problem. The bottom line is that you have to set yourself up to be able to profile different solutions, ans pick the best one (if you have determined that it actually matters).

Comment: Ok, but how is the stack smaller than the heap if they share the same memory region and grow towards eachother? That would mean: less stack usage -> more heap memory and less heap usage -> more stack memory, right?

Comment: @Yaeger the stack usually has a maximum size that is smaller than the maximum size allowed for the heap. Usually you don't hit the limit in either, but it can happen.

Comment: @juanchopanza Hmmm ok, I did some research and as you stated there is indeed a limit on the stack and the heap. My assumptions were incorrect ;). Thank you for your time. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The `std::vector` method would most likely be the preferred choice.  An alternative would be to return a `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> toBytes()
{
    std::unique_ptr<uint8_t[]> result(new uint8_t[size]);
    // ...
    return result;
}
```

This would only be useful if there was some limitation that prevented you from being able to utilize `std::vector`.